# Cloudsim- How to calculate totalCurrentRequestedRam of a VM?

Tags: cloudsim

I am working on SLA violation Time per Active Host(SLATAH). I want to consider three parameters CPU, RAM and Bw for calculation of this metric. Now, for considering this three parameters I need to calculate the totalCurrentRequestedRam.

The bellow code is the currentRequestedRam of a VM, now I need to totalCurrentRequestedRam, How Should I calculated ?

```
public int getCurrentRequestedRam() {
    if (isBeingInstantiated()) {
        return getRam();
    }
    return (int) (getCloudletScheduler().getCurrentRequestedUtilizationOfRam() * getRam());
}
```